# How to get the list of all IE / Chrome tabs window titles along with ProcessID using c#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, internet-explorer, system.diagnostics

I know I maybe duplicating this query but I couldn't find the correct solution hence posting.

I need to get each individual tab of IE and Chrome's **Processid** along with **WindowTitle** using c#.

I have tried using the following:

EnumWindows - which fetches the individual Window Title but not individual window handle and ProcessID. It fetches the parent window handle and ProcessID.

ShellWindows: which gives a list of all IE tabs window title but not the indvidual ProcessId.

System.Diagnostics.Process: which gives the individual tab's ProcessId but not the window Title.

For Chrome-System.Windows.Automation: this again gives the individual window title but not the individual ProcessId.

I need the corresponding processid for each window title because am displaying the entire list on a DataGridView in which ProcessId is unique.

Thanks.

Comment: However chrome spawns the process. If each tab has a separate process, there is no windows parent/process ownership mechanism because process aren't meant to be used like multi threaded application where process from chrome maps to thread in Windows which is always owned by a parent process.

Comment: Chrome has its own task manager, maybe that is a good way? As for other programs it should be a matter of finding threads of parent process. Chrome uses tabs/procss as a sort of hack, instead of using Windows specifics like surrogate process. So basically explorer is sacraficial com serrogate and chrome is non windows specific meaning it handles that.